# Display data from SQLite as dynamic cards with Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-listview, android-sqlite

Right now I get the usernames a string array from my database. I want to display it like that layout: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5WJN.png)

It should be dynamic, if the name is long, only one name per row,... Sometimes there will be 20 names and sometimes there will be only one name, so it needs to be flexible. I am new to Android Studio and not sure if it makes sence to use a listview or maybe even Text Views? Or maybe something else?

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use a Recyclerview with Flexbox Layout manager https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout

with flexWrap set.

```java
FlexboxLayoutManager layoutManager = new FlexboxLayoutManager(context);
        layoutManager.setFlexWrap(FlexWrap.WRAP);
        RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        // Create Custom RecyclerAdapter for data
        RecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(context,stringArrayList);
        RecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

RecyclerView is like listview but better performing.

Use an ArrayList not array as this is more flexible.

In the adapter each item is "drawn" in the `onBinViewHolder` and you can use a textbox for each name or your example looks like it uses Chips.

More details on RecyclerView at https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview